# Xamarin xaml Label String

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

I have the next code in xaml but i have a errors and i don´t know the reason

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Resources>
  <String name="app_name"> Cloud Client</String>
  <String name="title_section1">Section 1</String>
  <String name="title_section2">Section 2</String>
  <String name="title_section3">Section 3</String>
  <String name="activity_directory_contents_title">Contenido del directorio</String>
  <String name="activity_main_dialog_logout_title"> Titulo </String>

   </Resources>
```

in MainActivity.cs

SetTitle(Resource.String.activity_main_dialog_logout_title)

The error is next:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS0117  'Resource.String' does not contain a definition for 'activity_main_dialog_logout_title' Cloud_Client_Android    C:\Users\Developer\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Cloud_Client_Cross-Platform\Cloud_Client_Android\MainActivity.cs   58

Comment: it sounds like your code is referencing a resource "activity_main_dialog_logout_title" that is not defined in your resource file

Comment: If indeed but I have no idea how I do it, I am supposed to automatically create the ID's

Comment: try commenting out the line, compile, then comment it in again

Comment: also there is a space `name =` it shouldn't matter but remove it

Comment: it is the same no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the build action on the file (strings.xml) is set to "Android Resource"

And the format looks wrong, it should be like this (case is likely important):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string
        name="string_name"
        >text_string</string>
</resources>
```

When using Xamarin.Android you're not creating a Xaml file, its an android resource xml file. See the android site for help: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Strings.xml file is located on Resources/values (mind the caps and set the Strings.xml as Android Resource) and as matt said this is the correct xml format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="btn">OK</string>
</resources>
```